# Outflow boundary condition - second derivative of velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

Consider a fluid flow simulation in a pipe. At the outflow, instead of explicitly imposing a boundary condition, I linearly extrapolate information from the interior (for velocity components). This will translate to $$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} =\frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial ^2 w}{\partial x^2}= 0$$ at the boundary($x$ being axial direction). This kind of numerical condition has been used successfully throughout the literature (see page 262 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/V_Theofilis/publication/228464691_Advances_in_global_linear_instability_analysis_of_nonparallel_and_three-dimensional_flows/links/00b7d52aac68806e31000000.pdf)).

What I am interested is - what does this condition physically mean?

Any discussion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your formulation is $v$ the velocity in the streamwise or flow normal direction?

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson : In my formulation (which is 3D), I set the second derivative of all components of velocity to be zero.

Comment: This means, that the acceleration does not change in normal direction. But why the second derivative? Typically (and also in the reference you give), the velocity is prolonged over the boundary.

Comment: @Jan : You mean 'convective acceleration'?  The second derivative arises from the linear extrapolation.

Comment: I haven't seen this used before. In a practical sense, why does a first derivative outflow condition not suffice?

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson : The BC is more of a numerical one. Rather than specifying a 'hard' boundary condition, this extrapolates from the interior of the domain. This allows for passing of vorticity through the boundary without any reflection.

Comment: @Rhinocerotidae I'm trying to solve numerically a PDE with the same boundary conditions(BC). Can you please hint me where I can find a documentation/tutorial/example on applying such BC for numerical solutions?

Comment: I’ve seen the second derivative of u to be zero with v=0 at outlet (Kourta-Braza, then this prof had more advanced bc Jib-Braza, but I’m stuck at implementing it at the outlet), unsure how v component second derivative is also 0. Any refs how to get this bc with non-reflective condition?

Comment: @vogdb I know it’s pretty late but take three point scheme and express your points outside the domain in terms of points inside, then sub these values in your scheme at the boundary, this will change the coefficients of the scheme